# Maintain Tab index after post back with textchanged

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 3 textboxes that have AutoPostBack = true. On postback it's losing it's focus. I've been searching and tried many things but nothing is working.

The code below is a snippet of what i'm trying to do.

basically this first snippet isn't grabbing anything. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here

**Side note I'm not using Update Panel i'm using LayoutItemNestedControlContainer

```
        Dim ctrl = From control In wcICausedPostBack.Parent.Controls.OfType(Of WebControl)()
                   Where control.TabIndex > indx
                   Select control






Protected Sub txtDEPTH_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDEPTH.TextChanged
    UpdateProductTemp()

    txtDEPTH.Focus()
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim wcICausedPostBack As WebControl = CType(GetControlThatCausedPostBack(TryCast(sender, Page)), WebControl)
        Dim indx As Integer = wcICausedPostBack.TabIndex

        Dim ctrl = From control In wcICausedPostBack.Parent.Controls.OfType(Of WebControl)()
                   Where control.TabIndex > indx
                   Select control

        ctrl.DefaultIfEmpty(wcICausedPostBack).First().Focus()

    End If



End Sub

Protected Function GetControlThatCausedPostBack(ByVal page As Page) As Control
    Dim control As WebControl = Nothing
    Dim ctrlname As String = page.Request.Params.[Get]("__EVENTTARGET")

    If ctrlname IsNot Nothing AndAlso ctrlname <> String.Empty Then
        control = page.FindControl(ctrlname)
    Else

        For Each ctl As String In page.Request.Form
            Dim c As Control = page.FindControl(ctl)

            If TypeOf c Is TextBox OrElse TypeOf c Is DropDownList Then
                control = c
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return control
End Function
```

Comment: "I have 3 textboxes... On postback it's losing it's focus." What's losing its focus? Be precise. Format the code and include everything necessary.

Comment: Sorry the Tab Index is losing focus. If you make a change the autopost back event is fired and I would like the tab index to go to the next textbox however it goes to the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

Which version are you using? Because, when I try to set focus() of a  Textbox, the compiler gives me an error, because there is no such method. However, HTML provides an attribute, which auto focuses an focusable element.

Solution:

```
TextBoxToSetFocus.Attributes.Add("autofocus", "")
```

Regards,

Maheshvara

Comment: Maheshvara are you asking what version of .NET i'm using? .Net framework 4. Also this is what i'm to trying to accomplish http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=253

Comment: Did you try what I posted? By giving the attribute autofocus and removing it, you can just let the browser handle that stuff.

Comment: Yes it didn't work. But I did find a Solution. The issue was that the textboxes were in a DevExpress Layout group. So i had to change my textboxes into DevExpress Textboxes and then altered my Textchanged event